# Why turning on flash change the focus mode of the camera?

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I have 2 AF Focus Distance can be control by button and an On Off switch for flash.

Why IF ELSE for flashligh in updatePreview() will affect focus mode to auto? When I comment out that part (IF ELSE for flashligh), AF mode and Focus distance work fine with the btnFocus.

How to solve this while still can allow user to turn on and off the flashlight?

```java
    private float focusDistance = 0;
    private int flashSwitch = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textureView = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        //From Java 1.4 , you can use keyword 'assert' to check expression true or false
        assert textureView != null;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        btnFocus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFocus);
        btnFlash = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFlash);
        btnFocus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                changeFocus();
            }
        });
        btnFlash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Flash();
            }
        });
    }

    private void Flash() {
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            return;
        if(flashSwitch == 0 ) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Flash Turn On ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            flashSwitch = 1;
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Flash Turn Off ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            flashSwitch = 0;
        }
        createCameraPreview();
    }


    private void changeFocus() {
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            return;
        if(focusDistance == 0 )
            focusDistance = 10;
        else
            focusDistance = 0;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Focus Change "+ focusDistance, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        createCameraPreview();
    }

    private void createCameraPreview() {
        try{
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert  texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(),imageDimension.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    if(cameraDevice == null)
                        return;
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If you uncomment part the problem will come out when turn on flash and change focus.

```java
    private void updatePreview() {
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try{
//            if you uncomment this part the problem will come out 
//            if(flashSwitch == 0){
//                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
//            }
//            else{
//                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
//            }
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF);
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, focusDistance);
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(),null,mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

## Expected Output

Can manually turn on and off flash without affecting focus mode.

Comment: Maybe you want to change `Flash()` for something like `flash()` or `switchFlash()` to be consistent with camel case convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem might be on the way you set the requests.
You should create the preview first and only once, the way you have it, you are creating a preview everytime you switch flash and/or focus.
I suggest to create the preview in `onStart` with some defaults like:

```
focusDistance = 0;
flashSwitch = CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF;
```

And then in Flash() and `changeFocus()` instead of calling `createCameraPreview()` you call `updatePreview()`, your update preview would look something like this:

```
private void updatePreview() {
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try{
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, flashSwitch);
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, focusDistance);    
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(),null,mBackgroundHandler);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, can you share your contact with me please? Because I want to ask about getting every frame in preview as a bitmap to process it. I'm a self taught android developer doing image processing.

Comment: I sent you the email, if you didn't receive please let me know. Hope to hear from you soon.

Answer (score 0):

In `updatePreview()`, you're sending multiple capture requests to `cameraCaptureSessions` before settling all keys in `captureRequestBuilder`. Trying setting all keys first and then sending one repeating capture request.

```
private void updatePreview() {
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try{
            if(flashSwitch == 0){
                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            }
            else{
                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            }
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF);
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, focusDistance);

            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(),null,mBackgroundHandler);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will have a try later when I got to work
would you mind look at this in the mean time? 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56421471/how-to-manually-control-camera2-manual-focus)